# C# to VB.NET Conversion : 'Take (of T)' Error

Tags: c#, vb.net, byte

C# code

```
byte[] array = bytes.Take<byte>(num).ToArray<byte>();
```

VB.NET Converted Code (i tried multiable ones. same result)

```
Dim array As Byte() = bytes.Take(Of Byte)(num).ToArray(Of Byte)()
```

got an error on : `(of Byte)`

Error

```
Extension method 'Public Function Take(count As Integer) As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of TSource)' defined in 'System.Linq.Enumerable' is not generic (or has no free type parameters) and so cannot have type arguments
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have much experience with this, but it looks like if the VB compiler is able to infer the type arguments, it doesn't let you specify them explicitly. Assuming `bytes` is a `Byte` array (or an `IEnumerable(Of Byte)`), you should be able to use:

```
Dim array As Byte() = bytes.Take(num).ToArray()
```

Frankly it's a little odd to redundantly specify the type arguments in C#, too - I'd normally write:

```
byte[] array = bytes.Take(num).ToArray();
```