# Why can't generic extension method be called with explicit generic arguments?

Tags: .net, vb.net, generics, extension-methods

I have the following extension method:

```
Module MyModule

    <Extension()>
    Public Function MyExtension(Of T)(value As T, i As T) As Short
        Return Nothing 'omitted'
    End Function

End Module
```

I can call it in a variety of ways:

```
Dim fake As IFoo
fake.Bar().MyExtension(1)
MyModule.MyExtension(Of Integer)(fake.Bar(), 1)
```

But it seems to impossible to call it as an extension method with an explicit generic type parameter:

```
fake.Bar().MyExtension(Of Integer)(1)
```

Is there a way to do that in VB? I can do it easily in C# with this syntax:

```c#
IFoo fake = null;
fake.Bar().MyExtension<int>(1);
```

Comment: It's a good question actually. I initially misunderstood it and wrote a whole answer answering a different question :-D

Comment: I finally found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31227873/4934172) answered by [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) :). Hope that helps you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Extension Methods (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) (emphasis added):

> Extension methods enable you to "add" methods to existing types
>   without creating a new derived type, recompiling, or otherwise
>   modifying the original type. Extension methods are a special kind of
>   static method, but **they are called as if they were instance methods on
>   the extended type**. For client code written in C#, F# and Visual Basic,
>   there is no apparent difference between calling an extension method
>   and the methods that are actually defined in a type.

The difference between C# and VB is the interpretation of the highlight text above.

For C# extension method with these signatures:

```
public static short MyExtension<T>(this T value, T i)
{
    return default(short);
}

public static short MyExtension2<T1, T2>(this T1 value, T2 i)
{
    return default(short);
}
```

There corresponding use as extension methods would look like (ignoring that types could be inferred):

```
SomeType v0 = null;
SomeType v1 = null;
v1.MyExtension<SomeType>(v0);
v1.MyExtension2<SomeType, int>(2);
```

C# just allows calling static methods as though they are instance methods without putting any thought into "as if they were instance methods on the extended type" part.  VB took a more in-depth transformation approach to make the signature look as though it truly is an instance method.

The corresponding instance method signatures would look something like this:

```
internal class SomeType
{
    public short MyExtensionInstance(SomeType i)
    {
        return default(short);
    }

    public short MyExtension2Instance<T2>(T2 i)
    {
        return default(short);
    }

}
```

Calling the instance methods would look like this:

```
SomeType v0 = new SomeType();
SomeType v1 = new SomeType();
v1.MyExtensionInstance(v0);
v1.MyExtension2Instance<int>(2);
```

This is exactly the syntax that VB enforces for the extension methods as **they are called as if they were instance methods on the extended type**.

Now to answer your question; there is no way to force VB to act like C# in regards to this fundamental implementation difference.

In reality, I can not understand why you would prefer the C# style. Specifying the extended type is verbose and redundant.  I find it to also introduces an inconsistency with extension methods where the `this` argument is not generic by inducing a egg-chicken-egg (type-method-type) pattern where it is not needed nor beneficial.

Comment: I was trying to use this syntax only because I was testing a Roslyn diagnostic analyzer and I wanted to make sure it will work for every possible usage of an extension method. As I had a test case for this particular scenario in C# I wanted to have the same in VB

Answer (score 1):

The compile error you get is:

> Extension method 'Public Function MyExtension(i as Integer) As Short' defined in 'MyModule' is not generic (or has no free type parameters) and so cannot have type arguments

So as you can tell in the error message, the method signature has no generic arguments. So VB doesn't actually let you enter the generic type as it's already determined.

With IntelliSense, you can actually see the difference between VB and C#.

VB
[image]

C#
[image]

Notice how the call to the extension doesn't show the generic for VB but does for C#, which allows you to supply `<int>` even though it is redundant.

So if you actually want to supply a generic type, the extension method needs to allow one, just like how you have one parameter for the type you are extending and the subsequent parameters for the actual values to pass.

```
<Extension()>
Public Function MyExtension(Of T1, T2)(value As T1, i As T2) As Short
    Return Nothing 'omitted'
End Function

fake.Bar().MyExtension(Of Integer)(1) ' no compile error
```

Not sure what you are looking at doing but that's just an example. I'm not too familiar with extension methods, this was just my observation.